# Using breeze to do change tracking

Tags: breeze, change-tracking

I am new to Breeze and i was looking for some working example about change tracking. I want to enable or disable the save button if there are some changes on page. I want to have same functionality like creating dirty flag as we do in knockout.

On Breeze website i saw article about change tracking but couldnt follow it much. Any help is really appreciated. I have googled a lot but couldnt find any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Breeze website has documentation on [Change Tracking](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/change-tracking) and [Knockout data binding](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/databinding-knockout), but you've probably seen those.

To see it in action, look at the [TempHire sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/temphire-sample).  For example, the [details view](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/TempHire/TempHire/App/views/details.html) uses a `canSave` observable property that is exposed by the [details viewModel](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/TempHire/TempHire/App/viewmodels/details.js).